# Process incoming data with Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database to store measured weather data. (i.e. temperature, air pressure, etc.)

Let's say every 15 minutes a new value gets added to my db. I wanna use Firebase Functions to extract certain values automatically (maxima, minima, 24h high/low, etc.) because I want to display these values on my website. It seemed a good idea because in this way all the work would be done on the back-end and the web-js-code would just grab the values off of my db instead of querying endlessly.

Now I'm no expert on Firebase Functions and ran into some trouble trying to get Firebase to read and compare all these values. My db-tree looks something like this: [image: Firebase DB-Tree]

The idea is to use .onWrite to listen for new entries in, say, `'weather/temps'` and compare each new entry with `'history/extrema/maximum/temp'`. Now I dont really know how to read in the current maximum value inside the functions that would update it's value. So far, my code looks like this:

[image]

How can I read data in my function from any point in my db and use it for comparison etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to asynchronously get the "history/extrema/maximum/temp" and then compare and set. But that would be a costly operation and takes time!

In cloud functions, you can store global variable, they will survive until the function timesout. So if your function is not called for some time, the system destroys your function , and you loose the variable.

So a good way to do is,if the global variable,say "maxTemp" is null, read the "history/extrema/maximum/temp" and store it in a global varaible, then proceed to compare with new value, and if it higher, then update the "maxTemp" variable and the "history/extrema/maximum/temp" also.

Comment: how do you update global variables from within a function though? just like any local variable? (i.e. maxTemp = newvalue?) Tried this but it doesnt update maxTemp somehow

Comment: did you declare the variable outside all functions?

Comment: nvm it worked. Ran into another issue^^ thank you so much man =)